# How to send text to the Rich Text Editor found in page source

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

Could someone help me to locate textarea in 'Rich Text Editor'. Being struggling with that issue and could not find solution.
Tried with this (among other attempts):

```
List<WebElement> messageBody =  driver.findElements(By.xpath("//body[@class='cke_editable cke_editable_themed  cke_contents_ltr cke_show_borders']/p"));
    messageBody.get(0).sendKeys("Vamos con una apuesta para esta");
```

Below are screenshots how does it looks and also attached pagesource.
Thank you in advance
[image]

[image]

Here is part of page source:

```
<form role="form" id="user_message_form">
<div class="form-body">
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-12">  
<textarea id="user_message_editor" name="continut_mesaj" class="ckeditor form-control" rows="12" minlength="2" style="visibility: hidden; display: none;"></textarea>
<div id="cke_user_message_editor" class="cke_210 cke cke_reset cke_chrome cke_editor_user_message_editor cke_ltr cke_browser_webkit" dir="ltr" lang="en" role="application" aria-labelledby="cke_user_message_editor_arialbl">
<div class="cke_inner cke_reset" role="presentation">
<span id="cke_210_top" class="cke_top cke_reset_all" role="presentation" style="height: auto; user-select: none;"><span id="cke_218" class="cke_voice_label">Editor toolbars</span>
<div id="cke_210_contents" class="cke_contents cke_reset" role="presentation" style="height: 200px;"><span id="cke_303" class="cke_voice_label">Press ALT 0 for help</span><iframe src="" frameborder="0" class="cke_wysiwyg_frame cke_reset" style="width: 866px; height: 100%;" title="Rich Text Editor, user_message_editor" aria-describedby="cke_303" tabindex="0" allowtransparency="true"></iframe></div>
<iframe src="" frameborder="0" class="cke_wysiwyg_frame cke_reset" style="width: 866px; height: 100%;" title="Rich Text Editor, user_message_editor" aria-describedby="cke_303" tabindex="0" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
#document
<html dir="ltr" lang="en"><head><title data-cke-title="Rich Text Editor, user_message_editor">Rich Text Editor, user_message_editor</title><style data-cke-temp="1">html{cursor:text;*cursor:auto}
<head>...</head>
<body contenteditable="true" class="cke_editable cke_editable_themed cke_contents_ltr cke_show_borders" spellcheck="false"><p><br></p></body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a delta difference between the *HTML* within the *snapshot* and the text *HTML* you have provided.

- If the `Rich Text Editor` is not within any `<iframe>` you can use the following solution:

  ```
  WebElement messageBody = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//body[@class='cke_editable cke_editable_themed cke_contents_ltr cke_show_borders']/p"));
  messageBody.click();
  messageBody.sendKeys("Vamos con una apuesta para esta");
  ```
- If the `Rich Text Editor` is within the `<iframe>` with *attribute* **class="cke_wysiwyg_frame cke_reset"** you have to switch to the desired *iframe* first as follows:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.xpath("//iframe[@class='cke_wysiwyg_frame cke_reset']")));
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//body[@class='cke_editable cke_editable_themed cke_contents_ltr cke_show_borders']/p"))).click();
  messageBody.sendKeys("Vamos con una apuesta para esta");
  ```

Comment: thank you, it is inside iframe. That is why I had issue